# General weak law of large numbers, example from Chung's book.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve an example from the book "A Course in Probability Theory" by Chung, Third Edition page $118$.

How can I prove the following asymptotics:

$$n\cdot\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2 \ln(k)}}\sim \frac{c}{\ln(n)},$$
$$\frac{1}{n}\cdot \sum\limits_{k=3}^{n}{\frac{1}{ \log(k)}}\sim \frac{c}{\ln(n)}.$$

Any advice is wellcome.

Comment: [Compare them with appropriate integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)?